# C# - Couldn't get into the attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

This is first time I am using custom attributes and probably I'm doing something very wrong. Also what I am doing could be not the correct way to do this, so please correct me if I am wrong.

I am trying to develop a web/text based game. I want to deny account who has not created a character yet but I don't want to do it in every method. So I decided to create an attribute doing it and stop execution of method if attribute returns false.

Here is my attribute

```
public class EnsureCharacter:Attribute
{
    public bool EnsureCharacterAttr()
    {
        var member = Membership.GetUser();
        var entity = new dixraEntities();
        var character = entity.Character
                    .Where(c => c.AccountId == (int)member.ProviderUserKey)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

        if (character != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

And in my controller

```
    [EnsureCharacter]
    public ActionResult CreateCharacter()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is, I put a breakpoint into the attribute and I'm never going in there. What am I missing here? Or is there any better way to do this control in every control?

Comment: You put a random method on your Attribute (EnsureCharacterAttr())... when would you want it to be executed? You need to hook this attribute into something that validates it with that call. Just putting the attribute there doesn't do that.

Comment: @Tim i want it executed before the actual method. I'm not sure how can i do what you said.

Comment: As a side note, you should name it `EnsureCharacterAttribute` to follow the convention. You can still use it as `[EnsureCharacter]`.

Comment: @vgSefa attributes aren't "executed" before the method they're applied to. They're not even necessarily executed until they're checked for. And with yours, you've got a method that you need to specifically call. How would you expect your random Boolean-returning method to get called?